# убрать кнопку создать свою карту

Tags: yandex-maps-api

в новой версии появилась такая кнопка
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXFVB.jpg

можно ее как-то убрать?

Comment: map.removeControl(new YMaps."сдесь какое-то из свойств"), какое не могу сказать , посмотрите объект YMaps

Answer (score 1):

помогло отключение через параметр, странно, что эта кнопка относится к кнопке "как добраться"/"Открыть в Яндекс картах"

suppressMapOpenBlock: true

Answer (score 1):

Используй CSS

```
.ymaps-2-1-79-gotoymaps__container,
.ymaps-2-1-79-gototech {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Первый класс это кнопка "Открыть в Яндекс картах", а второй это ссылка "Создать свою карту"